# Action with a string array as parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, arrays, action

I want to call an action with something similar to this uri:

```
http://server/controller/action/?columns=firstname&columns=lastname&columns=age
```

and use it like this:

```
public ActionResult Action(string[] columns)
{

}
```

how do I do it?

Comment: FYI. Сlarification about POST request - http://stackoverflow.com/a/2527206/1193727

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google is my friend ;)

```
http://server/controller/action/?columns[]=firstname&columns[]=lastname&columns[]=age
```

Edit:

Actually you just write as I did in my original question. The reason to why I didn't get it working in the first place is that I used "column" in the query string and "columns" in as action parameter.

Comment: worked thanks. had to make sure the name of the argument in the action method was the same as the array in the url.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the difference between get and post parameters, but your original post works perfectly good with post parameters. In fact, when using []'s in post parameters the array becomes null in the action parameter. I found this out when jQuery 1.4 started adding []'s in json arrays when posting. See: http://www.dovetailsoftware.com/blogs/kmiller/archive/2010/02/24/jquery-1-4-breaks-asp-net-mvc-actions-with-array-parameters