# How to pass collection of integers to the action controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an URL of the following manner: `//...../controller/action?a=1&a=2&a=3&a=4`

Is it possible to make controller to convert a into collection of `int` like in the example below:

```
public  ActionResult Action(int[] a) {.....}
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Action with a string array as parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023363/action-with-a-string-array-as-parameter). Make it `?a[]=1&a[]=2...`.

Comment: Could you tell us the context as we may to give a better solution that way. AKA what the user interface is, why you have this list of `Int`s

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can have multiple query string parameters with the same name. Probably has to be `//...../controller/action?a=1,2,3,4`

```
public  ActionResult Action(string a) 
{
    var aStrs = a.Split(',');
    var aInts = aStrs.Select(int.Parse).ToList();
}
```