# Passing Array to Action from a $.post

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am having trouble passing my array via a $.post.

### The Javascript

```
var privIDs = [1,2,4,5];
$.post("/Home/GrantPrivilegesToUser", { privilegeIDs: privIDs }, function (data) {
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data.success);
});
```

### The Action

```
public ActionResult GrantPrivilegesToUser(int[] privilegeIDs)       
{
    return Json(new {success=true});
}
```

The action sees privilegeIDs as null.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;` for you jQuery ajax setting.  In jQuery 1.4 they changed the way items are serialized in a form post.

please see:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/nested-param-serialization

And:
[How can I post an array of string to ASP.NET MVC Controller without a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309115/how-can-i-post-an-array-of-string-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-without-a-form/2527206#2527206)

Answer (score 1):

I use JSON to pass data as a string using the JSON2 library: http://www.json.org/js.html

```
var privIDs = [1,2,3,4,5];
var data = JSON.stringify({privilegeIDs : privIDs});
$.POST("/Home/GrantPrivilegesToUser", data, function (data) {
   alert("Data Loaded: " + data.success);
});
```

And the action would use the WebMethod type:

```
[WebMethod]
public object Entry_GetFormOptions(string privilegeIDs)
{
   return new {success=true};
}
```

There are both built-in and 3rd party functions for parsing the received JSON to access the privilege IDs.

Let me know if this does or does not help.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing.  Might be helpful to someone...

```
var privIDs = [1,2,4,5];

$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/Home/UpdatePrivileges",
     data: { privilegeIDs: privIDs },
     traditional: true,
     success: function (json) {
          alert(json.success);
     }
});
```

If you use .ajax instead of .post you can include `traditional: true`