# Asp.net MVC - Mapping comma separated string to string array in action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a comma separated string in a textbox, I want to pass this string as string array to an action method. Could anyone tell me how can I achieve this. thanks.

I am using MVC 1.0.

Views:

```
<input type="text" name="fruits" /> -- Contains the comma seperated values
```

Action method

```
public ActionResult Index(string[] fruits)
{

}
```

Comment: if you are using jQuery then i can suggest you a very simple way!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a custom model binder to achieve this. Create a class like this to do the split.

```
public class StringSplitModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    #region Implementation of IModelBinder

    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (!bindingContext.ValueProvider.ContainsKey(bindingContext.ModelName))
        {
            return new string[] { };
        }

        string attemptedValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider[bindingContext.ModelName].AttemptedValue;
        return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(attemptedValue) ? attemptedValue.Split(',') : new string[] { };
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then you can instruct the framework to use this model binder with your action like this.

```
public ActionResult Index([ModelBinder(typeof(StringSplitModelBinder))] string[] fruits)
{
}
```

Instead of applying the `ModelBinder` attribute to action method parameters you can also register the custom model binder globally in the application start method of your Global.asax.

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(string[]), new StringSplitModelBinder());
```

This will split the single string value posted to the array you require.

Please note that the above was created and tested using MVC 3 but should also work on MVC 1.0.

Comment: I am getting this error.. System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult>' does not contain a definition for 'GetValue' and no extension method 'GetValue' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: For fixing this I modified to use like this, bindingContext.ValueProvider[bindingContext.ModelName].AttemptedValue;

Comment: Your code doesn't handles the null case scenario? So its throwing object reference error when null value is passed.

Comment: I've updated the code of the model binder, please check if it works now.

Comment: Thanks a Lot for taking time to explain these stuffs... +1 and I will mark it as answer..

Answer (score 6):

Pass the string (with the commas) of your textbox directly to the controller action and create the array inside of the action.

```
public ActionResult Index(string fruits)
{
    var fruitsArray = fruits.Split(',');
    // do something with fruitArray
}
```

Comment: thanks... But I dont want this solution. Is there any other way?
I know this solution. MY requirement is like that. I just want to know other ways of achieving this..

Comment: fruits is a parameter. Do you mean you can't modify the signature of the Index action?

Comment: Yes. I dont want the signature of index. Because fruits ..etc paratmeters are persent in another business class..

Comment: When you can't modify the controller to change or overload the Index action, I only see a solution with JavaScript. Like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309115/how-can-i-post-an-array-of-string-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-without-a-form - That way it can be accomplished, although I don't like it.

Comment: Depending on the reason that you have a comma separated list, you could also repeat the input tag with one value per tag: <input name="fruit" value="apple" /><input name="fruit" value="orange" /> and then you will get an array in the controller called "fruit"