# Serialized JSON Object appearing as Null at controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-controller

I have a stringified JSON object that appears properly in an alert, appears properly  in the post section in the browser debugger, *but in the controller it appears as null*.  I'm not sure how it is losing the information.

Here is the JS code:

```
 var assessmentStatus = [];

            $("select.assessmentSelect").each(function () {
                assessmentStatus.push({
                    assessmentname: $(this).attr("id"),
                    assessmentstatus: $(this).val()
                });


            });
alert(JSON.stringify(assessmentStatus));


            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("testAS")',
                type: "POST",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    AS: assessmentStatus,
                    AS2: assessmentStatus

                })

            });
```

this is what is appearing in the alert:

```
[{"assessmentname":"testassessment","assessmentstatus":"Design"},{"assessmentname":"DepressionUpload","assessmentstatus":"Design"}]
```

this is what is appearing in the post:

```
[Object { assessmentname="testassessment", assessmentstatus="Design"}, Object { assessmentname="DepressionUpload", assessmentstatus="Design"}]
```

my controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult testAS (string[] AS, string AS2)

string[] AS returns [0]null  [1]null
string AS2 just returns null.
```

Why is it not getting stringified when being sent to the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be attempting to pass an array of complex objects with 2 properties:

```
assessmentStatus.push({
    assessmentname: $(this).attr("id"),
    assessmentstatus: $(this).val()
});
```

to a simple array of strings: `string[] as`. This is obviously not gonna work.

So start by defining a view model:

```
public class AssessmentViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

then adapt your controller action:

```
public ActionResult TestAS(AssessmentViewModel[] assessments)
{
    ...
}
```

and finally your javascript:

```
var assessments = [];
$('select.assessmentSelect').each(function () {
    assessments.push({
        name: $(this).attr("id"),
        status: $(this).val()
    });
});
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("testAS")',
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ assessments: assessments })
});
```

Comment: This did the trick!  I knew that string[] didn't look right but I was unsure how to address it.  Thank you Darin!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to encode the parameters yourself, for what looks like a simple action. Just hand jQuery an object with your properties and it'll encode it for you.

```
       $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("testAS")',
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: {
                AS: assessmentStatus,
                AS2: assessmentStatus

            )

        });
```

Comment: That returns the following error:   </b>System.ArgumentException: Invalid JSON primitive: AS.<br><br>

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this before.  You need to set jQuery's ajaxSettings.traditional = true.   Some time ago, they changed how they serialize arrays. and it messed up asp.net mvc.

This question talks about it:

[How can I post an array of string to ASP.NET MVC Controller without a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309115/how-can-i-post-an-array-of-string-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-without-a-form)

as does this:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/nested-param-serialization

So just put:

```
jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
```

Then do like Pointy said, and don't stringify your data.