# Json data list, array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

Here I have got problem:

OneCar -> when I take only one argument I can see value and everything is OK

but when I try take list of arguments in ListCar1 and ListCar2 I can see only null

I believe this is small mistake but I don't know how to fix it.

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult DodajTematSave(string OneCar, string[] ListCar1, List<string> ListCar2)
        {
        }
```

Here is Json action

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function Save() {

        var mycars = new Array()
        $("[name^='CarString']").each(function () {
            mycars.push(this.value);
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("DodajTematSave", "StronaGlowna")',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                OneCar: mycars[0]
                ListCar1: mycars
                ListCar2: mycars
            },
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            error: function () {
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.Success) {
                    alert('success');
                }

            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

**Correct answer:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function Save() {

        var mycars = new Array()
        $("[name^='CarString']").each(function () {
            mycars.push(this.value);
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("DodajTematSave", "StronaGlowna")',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                OneCar: mycars[0]
                ListCar1: mycars
                ListCar2: mycars
            },
            type: "POST",
            traditional: true,
            async: false,
            error: function () {
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.Success) {
                    alert('success');
                }

            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `traditional: true` parameter to the `$.ajax` call. Details can be found in this [jQuery forum thread](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/nested-param-serialization) or in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2527206/728795).

Comment: Great answer, only this small thing and is okay :) many thanks :)