# Issue while sending array of objects to server in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on an application using `ASP.NET MVC 4`. I am trying to send and array of objects to the controller. My view contains:

```
<input type="hidden" id="1" name="Persons" value='[
 {"Id":1,"Name":"Abc","Description":"this is desc"},
 {"Id":2,"Name":"def","Description":"this is desc"},         
 {"Id":4,"Name":"ghi","Description":"this is desc"}]'
/>
```

And my controller action is like this:

```
public ActionResult create(List<Person> Persons)
{
  //Here the Persons count is always 0, why ?
}
```

When i post my form, i always get Persons count 0. Can anybody please help me with this issue ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I post an array of string to ASP.NET MVC Controller without a form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309115/how-can-i-post-an-array-of-string-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-without-a-form)

Comment: @DustinDavis thanks for response but i do not want to send my array with ajax. I want to send it with form.

Comment: Read this http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your input value to:

```
{Persons: [
    {"Id":1,"Name":"Abc","Description":"this is desc"},
    {"Id":2,"Name":"def","Description":"this is desc"},         
    {"Id":4,"Name":"ghi","Description":"this is desc"}
]}
```