# Mvc: get values from json using javascript arrays to mvc controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, arrays, json, linq-to-sql

I need to read each value from a json result i request to a controller action.
this is my **client side**.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "List",
        data: { firstArray: arrayCountries, secondArray: arrayLang },
        success: function (result) {

             //here i need each value from json, but it's not working for me   
        },
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true
    });
```

Ok now i use this way because i need to send 2 javascript arrays and after finding a lot this way works for me.

And this is my **server side**. According to [How can I post an array of string to ASP.NET MVC Controller without a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309115/how-can-i-post-an-array-of-string-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-without-a-form) i have created this.

```
public ActionResult List(List<String> firstArray, List<String> secondArray)
{
    //But here i need a list of sections, so i call a method for that
      var sections = SomeClass.getSections(fistArray, secondArray);

    //And return the json with the collection 
      return Json(sections, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Now this is my **getSections Method**

```
public static IEnumerable getSections(List<String> firstArray, List<String>secondArray)
{
    entities db = new entities();

    var result = from values in db.Sections
                 where ... 
                 select new SectionsModel{ // do something  };

    return result.OrderBy(p => p.Description);
}
```

Now im getting well json in client side but i don't know how to acces it, and how can i get each value from it ? ... thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse it first, after that you can just access the properties similarly as what you would do in .NET

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "List",
        data: { firstArray: arrayCountries, secondArray: arrayLang },
        success: function (result) {

             var sections = JSON.parse(result);

             // access properties here
        },
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true
    });
```

Comment: im getting firebug JSON.parse: unexpected character ... is something wrong with json format ?

Comment: What is the value of result when the call completes?

Comment: it's something like [object Object],[object Object]

Comment: thanks for your help finally with `result[0].property` i can get values. :)