# ajax post an array of strings to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Trying to post an array of strings to controller

My controller

```
public ActionResult GetMessage(List<string> ancestry)
{
}
```

My javascript

```
var s = ["a", "b", "c"];

$.post(newareaurl, { s: JSON.stringify(s) }, function (data) {

});
```

But the controller receives the data as a List with single element containing "[\"a\",\"b\",\"c\"]", I'm expecting it could receive a List with three elements.

I have tried setting the traditional style param serialization using traditional: true but 
it gives me "[object Object]" value in the controller

```
$.ajax({
  url: newareaurl,
  type: 'POST',
  data: { s: s },
  traditional: true,
  success: function (newTerritory) {
       console.log(newTerritory);
  },
  error: function () {

  }
  });
```

How to properly post the array?

Comment: try this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309115/how-can-i-post-an-array-of-string-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-without-a-form

Comment: hi thanks for reply, my problem turns out that I didn't check the typeof the javascript var I was processing with. After I convert the object to array, it worked *of course still using traditional set to true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the method to convert object to array

var nArray = jQuery.makeArray(s);

worked