# Post a List of Objects to Controller Without a Form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a simple test scenario with the following view model:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public int Number1 { get; set; }
    public int Number2 { get; set; }
    public int Number3 { get; set; }
}
```

And ActionResult in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestMethod(List<TestViewModel> testList)
{
    // irrelevant code here
}
```

Then the following javascript code in the View to post to the Controller:

```
var testList = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    testList.push({
        Number1: i,
        Number2: 2,
        Number3: 3
    });
}
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("TestMethod")',
    data: { testList: testList },
    dataType: 'json',
    //traditional: true
});
```

In google chrome, it sends the following in the form data:

```
testList[0][Number1]:0
testList[0][Number2]:2
testList[0][Number3]:3
.
.
testList[9][Number1]:9
testList[9][Number2]:2
testList[9][Number3]:3
```

Then when it hits the TestMethod in the Controller, `testList` is a `List<TestModel>` with a length of 10, but all the properties are set to `0`

I tried with `traditional: true` and when inspecting the traffic it sends the following:

```
testList:[object Object]
.
.
testList:[object Object]
```

And `testList` is null in TestMethod in the Controller.

Maybe it's just late and I'm not thinking correctly, but what am I doing wrong? Why aren't the values of the individual items in `List<TestViewModel> testList` not being set?

I've seen this question: [How can I post an array of string to ASP.NET MVC Controller without a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309115/how-can-i-post-an-array-of-string-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-without-a-form) but that doesn't seem to work for when the list is a custom object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after 3 hours of banging my head against the wall, I just discovered the solution was to post the data as json. Hopefully this helps someone else in the future:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("TestMethod")',
    contentType: 'application/json', // added
    data: JSON.stringify(testList), // changed
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Now I can sleep without wondering about this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a Prefix in your Action like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestMethod([Bind(Prefix = "testList")] List<TestViewModel> testList)
{
    // irrelevant code here
}
```