# How to pass an array and other parameter from jquery to controller in ASP.NET MVC4?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am able to pass an array from jquery to controller with the help from

[How can I post an array of string to ASP.NET MVC Controller without a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309115/how-can-i-post-an-array-of-string-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-without-a-form)

Now I need to pass one more parameter including array. How can I able to pass array and int parameters from jquery to controller?

Here is what I tried.

jquery

```
var postData = { values: itemIdsList, typeId: typeId }; //trying to pass typeId

 $.ajax({
    url: '/Orders/AddValuesType',
    //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: postData,
    dataType: "json",
    type: 'POST',
    traditional:true,
    success: function (result)
    {
        alert('success');
    }
});
```

controller

```
 public void AddValuesType(List<string> values, int typeId )
 {
    ...
 }
```

TIA

Comment: What is the RequestHeader's `Post Data`? check it in Firebug/chrome network tab. it should work if you pass correctly

Comment: Thanks, I had a different variable name in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I had different variable name in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work for you

```
var postData= {};
postData.ID = 'id';
postData.values = [];
//foreach
postData.values.push({'string'});
```

then send it like you have in your ajax call.  hopefully this helps.