# Pass two dimensional array from view to controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Is passing a 2 dimensional array from the view to the controller a possibility?
My view mimics a spreadsheet. It has 20 columns and 500 rows of text areas (possibly not the best way to accomplish this). How do I get these values to the controller, while still being able to track which row each value belongs to?

The solution for passing a simple array is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309115/how-can-i-post-an-array-of-string-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-without-a-form), any ideas on 2D? What should the action method parameter look like? I've tried

```
string[][] values
```

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 and Razor.

Comment: It would need to be the same as the model that you passed in to the view.  Either `string[][]` or `string[,]`

Comment: Just to clarify. The view can't pass data to the controller. The controller create the view. You think the client, right?

Comment: @Péter No, I'm referring to submitting view data to the controller.

Comment: My bad, I was missing the content type. Thanks guys!