# jquery ajax POST to ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have this ajax call and I am passing an array with it that looks like so `["ANC0001-Pin Lot"]` and I am trying to pass it to asp.net. I can see in the network console under 'Request Payload' my array is there.

Here is the jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/vendorProject/api/connection/updateVendorItem",
    data: JSON.stringify({ edittedItems: editHolder }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert('success');
    },
    failure: function (errMsg) {
        alert('failed');
    }
});
```

and here is my ASP.NET Controller:

```
public List<VendorUpdateClass> updateVendorItem(Array edittedItems)
{
    ConnectionClass jobs = new ConnectionClass();
    return jobs.updateVendors(edittedItems);
}
```

`updateVendors` method:

```
 public List<VendorUpdateClass> updateVendors(Array items)
{
    VendorUpdateCell = new List<VendorUpdateClass>();
    VendorUpdateClass vendorUpdatedItem = new VendorUpdateClass();

    for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++ ){
        vendorUpdatedItem.job = "aaa";
        vendorUpdatedItem.task = "bbb";
        vendorUpdatedItem.vendor = "ccc";

        VendorUpdateCell.Add(vendorUpdatedItem);
    }

    return VendorUpdateCell;
}
```

I am getting and 500 Internal Server Error:

```
    {  
       "Message":"An error has occurred.",
       "ExceptionMessage":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
       "ExceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException",
       "StackTrace":"   at VendorProject.Models.ConnectionClass.updateVendors(Array items)\r\n   
at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary 2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter 1.GetResult()\r\n   
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter 1.GetResult()\r\n   
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter 1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter 1.GetResult()\r\n   
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
    }
```

Without the loop this does work. When I put in the loop, this gives me a 500 error. Why is it doing this and how can I fix this?

Comment: What does the data look like that is being posted?

Comment: `["ANC0001-Pin Lot"]`

Comment: `["ANC0001-Pin Lot", "ANC0002-Pin Lot"]`

Comment: `{edittedItems: ["ANC0001-Pin Lot", "ANC0002-Pin Lot"]}`

Comment: I guess that the items array is null and when you call Length on it it throws an null reference error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public List<VendorUpdateClass> updateVendorItem(string[] edittedItems)
    {
        ConnectionClass jobs = new ConnectionClass();
        return jobs.updateVendors(edittedItems);
    }
```

You also could try replacing the string array with a `List<string>`

I also found this [How can I post an array of string to ASP.NET MVC Controller without a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309115/how-can-i-post-an-array-of-string-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-without-a-form)

Maybe you could get some inspiration there

Answer (score 1):

Right now you're posting an object that contains a property called `edittedItems` (side note: you probably meant `editedItems` with one "t") whose value is an array.

Contrast this with your controller action which expects *just* an array. You need to change your AJAX request to just POST an array instead:

```
data: JSON.stringify(editHolder)
```

And then as [@JOSEFtw mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30466755/497356), you should probably use  a `string[]` or `List<string>` instead of `Array`.

Answer (score 0):

Now try this method, i have updated id, becuase i could be crash due to null reference `items.Length`

```
public List<VendorUpdateClass> updateVendors(Array items)
        {
            VendorUpdateCell = new List<VendorUpdateClass>();
            VendorUpdateClass vendorUpdatedItem = new VendorUpdateClass();

            if (items == null && items.Length < 1)
                return VendorUpdateCell;

            for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
            {
                vendorUpdatedItem.job = "aaa";
                vendorUpdatedItem.task = "bbb";
                vendorUpdatedItem.vendor = "ccc";

                VendorUpdateCell.Add(vendorUpdatedItem);
            }

            return VendorUpdateCell;
        }
```

write this line before `for` loop

`if (items == null && items.Length < 1)
                    return VendorUpdateCell;`