# AJAX can't received data to controller MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I send data by ajax to mvc controller.
I get to the correct method but without data.
I tried to get `List<string>` but its null

js code:

```
function sendDataCreateMilestone(parameters) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/QRCNew/create",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(parameters)
    });
}
```

server:

here i revived all the time null

```
public ActionResult Create (List<string> ids, string collection)
{
    do....
}
```

Comment: What are the "parameters"?

Comment: You can refer this. It's exactly your problem.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309115/how-can-i-post-an-array-of-string-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-without-a-form[1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309115/how-can-i-post-an-array-of-string-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-without-a-form

Comment: @Dev-One - parameter is  array. I can see my data being send to server from client but the server doesn't receive it

Comment: You need to show what `parameters` is

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found my mistake , correct answer  is

```js
function sendDataCreateMilestone(parameters) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/QRCNew/create",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { collection: parameters }
    });
}

server:

  public ActionResult Create (string collection)
        {
            do ...
        }
```

Comment: $.ajax does not work for me. I have to use XMLHttpRequest and then it only sends null. This should be easy and yet Microsoft has made it incredibly difficult