# How to pass string array to controller using ajax?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

```
// something defined deleteArr and pass values to it
var postData = { deleteArr: deleteArr };
if(deleteArr.length > 0)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("Delete", "ASZ01")",
            type: "POST",
            data: postData,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response) {
                alert("success.");
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(deleteArr[0]);
            }
        });
        deleteArr.length = 0;
    }
```

The above code is javascript.
Until $.ajax begin I can confirm that values in array is correct in immediate window,but when it comes to error: I got "undefined".
And the following is my function in controller

```
public void Delete(List<string> deleteArr)
    {
        service.Delete(deleteArr);
    }
```

The second question is that I set breakpoint on that function but it can't stop.
I think maybe my ajax form is wrong?

Comment: Please refer to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309115/how-can-i-post-an-array-of-string-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-without-a-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stringify to `JSON`, add the `dataType: 'json'` and then pass and also correct your `""`

```
var postData = JSON.stringify({ deleteArr: deleteArr });

if(deleteArr.length > 0)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: @Url.Action("Delete", "ASZ01"),
            type: "POST",
            data: postData,
            dataType: 'json'
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response) {
                alert("success.");
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(deleteArr[0]);
            }
        });
        deleteArr.length = 0;
    }
```

Comment: is `datatype:json` required. ?

Comment: @Reddy I think yes

Comment: I thought it was only required if the return type from the server will be a JSON. For passing to server I dont think its necessary..

Comment: @Suren Srapyan, dataType is not required if return type format coming from server is not matter.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Small change to your `postData`

```
var postData = { deleteArr: JSON.stringify(deleteArr) };
```

Idea is to convert your array data into string format ie:JSON and posting to the server, The default Model binder of MVC framework will handle the part to convert them into `List<string>` for you