# Pass array to Controller Action via AJAX

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I saw similar questions, but none helps me.
I have the simplest code:

```
    public JsonResult JsonGetStatesInfo(object[] instructions)
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {

            return Json(String.Empty);
        }
        else
            throw new NoAjaxRequestException();
    }
```

and client side:

```
            var instructions = [];
            instructions.push('abc');
            instructions.push('ddd');
            instructions.push('assdbc');
            var inst = JSON.stringify(instructions);
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                data: { 'instructions': inst },
                traditional: true,
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '/State/JsonGetStatesInfo',
                type: 'post',
                success: function (resp) {
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert(data.error);
                }
            });
```

On client side I tried with JSON.stringify, without JSON.stringify, with traditional: true, without traditional: true

On server side I tried as parameter : object[], object, List< object >, List< string >, IEnumerable< string > etc

Nothing worked! How to do it correctly?

**SOLVED**:
My problem was trivial - one from real values of array had HTML Tag. Just need add [ValidateInput(false)] to action method

Comment: Do you get any error messages? If you put a breakpoint in the controller method, is it hit?

Answer (score 4):

You just need the following settings:

### Pass array of `string` to a MVC Action by Ajax:

**Controller:**

```
public JsonResult MyAction(string[] instructions)
{
    // Your codes
}
```

**View:**

```
$.ajax({
       data: { 'instructions': ['abc', 'dcs', 'arr'] }, // << Without JSON.stringify 
       traditional: true,  // << Important line
       url: '/State/MyAction',
       type: 'post',
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function (resp) {
            // Your codes
       }
});
```

> Using `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` is recommended too.

---

### Pass array of `int` to a MVC Action by Ajax:

Also I use bellow codes to path an `array of int` to an `Action`

**Controller:**

```
public JsonResult MyAction(int[] instructions)
{
    // Your codes
}
```

**View:**

```
$.ajax({
       data: { 'instructions': [1, 2, 3] }, // << Without JSON.stringify 
       traditional: true,  // << Important line
       url: '/State/MyAction',
       type: 'get',
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function (resp) {
            // Your codes
       }
});
```

Comment: Helped me thanks! Btw didn't needed the  traditional: true,

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

```
public ActionResult JsonGetStatesInfo(string[] instructions)
{
   return new JsonResult
        {
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
            Data = new { result = instructions.Length}
        };
}
```

Client side

```
 var instructions = ['abc', 'dcs', 'arr'];
 $.post('/State/JsonGetStatesInfo', { instructions: instructions },
      function (data) {
       if (data.result!= null && data.result!= undefined) {
        alert(data.result);
    }
});
```

Try this...

Answer (score 1):

At least, you can pass javascript array as a string and deserialize it in the controller

```
public JsonResult JsonGetStatesInfo(string instructions)

var instructionsArray= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(instructions);
```

Or use new Array like explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/310136/3063094

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

To you AJAX call, And please delete the:

```
JSON.stringify(instructions);
```

Because you are trying to stringify an object, which will be sent to the server as a string rather than an object (and the server side expects an object).

you can also delete the

```
traditional: true,
ache: false,
```

Comment: I get client error: "Invalid JSON primitive instructions"

Comment: Try using JSON.stringify with the suggestion above.