# Array variable passed to controller is null

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Below is my Js code

```
 function Table_to_Array() {
    var myTableArray = $("#tbl_CGT tr").map(function () {
        return $(this).find(':input').map(function () {
            return this.value;
        }).get();
    }).get();
    return myTableArray;
}

function send_to_server()
{
    var result = Table_to_Array();
    //var data = {
    //    Array: result
    //};

    var params = {
        url: '@Url.Action("test2", "Annex1")',
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        traditional : true,
        //data: JSON.stringify(data),
        data: {Array:JSON.stringify(result)},
        success: function (result) { alert('Ok! It worked.'); },
        error: function (result) { alert('Warning! It failed.'); }
    };
    $.ajax(params);
}
```

It convert table values into an array and pass it to ActionResult in controller

It is creating array very well

[image: Click Here]

But in controller it is coming null

```
public ActionResult test2(string[] Array)
    {
        string val = Array[1].ToString();
        return View("Index");
    }
```

What changes I need to do in it

Comment: Why dont you use Model ? BDW change string[] to List<string>

Comment: In your controller action `string[] Array`,`Array` needs to be the same name as in Js

Comment: @IrshadJm he has same name "Array" .... But he should change that name also

Comment: yes, he can not give `Array` as name

Comment: Ok , I changed the name to data_holder and it is sending data now , but still alert in error statement is still executing and showing alert('Warning! It failed.');

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I post an array of string to ASP.NET MVC Controller without a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309115/how-can-i-post-an-array-of-string-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-without-a-form)