# Fetch Data From jquery (Ajax) to Controller in IEnumerable<--------->

Tags: jquery, ajax, controller, jqgrid

Hello Am Facing problem in Fetching Data and Transferring to Controller

Below is My JQuery Code Using Ajax

```
$("#save").click(function () {
       
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/PCM/PCMPost',
            dataType: "json",
            data: { final: JSON.stringify(final) },
            //data: JSON.stringify({ final: final }),
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Succeded");
            }
        })
    })
```

intialized like this

```
var final=[];
```

final array looks like after push operation, in console and it has expected data to

```
(2)[{...},{...}]
```

controller code

```
public ActionResult PCMPost(IEnumerable<ProductCategaryMapping> final)
{
      return RedirectToAction("ProductCategaryMappingDisplay", "PCM");
}
```

while debugging "final" is showing null

i dont know where am going wrong
please help me out

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309115/how-can-i-post-an-array-of-string-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-without-a-form

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  . by getting the Json data in IEnumerable<>type as parameter in controller
 `public ActionResult PCMPost(IEnumerable<ProductCategaryMapping> final)`
i will use this parameter and store data of this parameter to DB (pass this param to repository to store)

however to do this operation . am getting count=0 while debugging (in controller )
so i kept controller empty.

note: going inside ajax sucess . only issue is jquery  data not getting in controller parameter

Comment: Apologies, I thought you were making a GET, not a POST

Comment: `$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/PCM/PCMPost',
            data: JSON.stringify({ final: final }),
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Succeded");
            }
        })`

ya tried . still not working . finding "final null" in controller @RoryMcCrossan please help me out

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify(final),`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan tried `data: JSON.stringify(final),` ,`data: JSON.stringify({ final: final }), `,`data: { final: JSON.stringify(final) },` all this way tried . still final is null in controller.

`{ProductCode: '01', ProductName: 'HIMALAYA ', Division: 'CP', Category: 'HIMALAYA', SubCategory: 'FAIRNESS', …}
Capacity: 0
Category: "HIMALAYA"
Division: "CP"
IsPriorityUpdate: 1
Priority1per: "100"
Priority2per: "0"
Priority3per: "0"
Priority_1: "1145"
Priority_2: ""
ProdPity: 1
ProductCode: "0011"
ProductName: "HIMALAYA FAC CREAM"
SubCategory: "FAIRNESS CREAM"
[[Prototype]]: Object`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan after converting to json . data look like above {productCode-------object}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send data without converting it to string.

```
$("#save").click(function () {
   
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/PCM/PCMPost',
        dataType: "json",
        data: { final:final },           
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Succeded");
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: tq.  it worked fine . tq so much for helping me out